# Set status bar colour for different view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistatusbar

I have 6 view controllers. I'd like to set the status bar of my first view controller to black and then the other 5 to white. All view controllers are in a push stack.

I've tried to implement

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]

- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle { 
return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```

That does not seem to work. I've also tried playing with the apps plist properties. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change Background colour of status bar then that's possible.
you have to change `UIWindow 's background colour` to your preferred colour. try following

e.g.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window].backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

and if you want to change text colour then just try

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed this settings in Plist

**View controller-based status bar appearance** to **YES**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've just set that and nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things.

1. View controller-based status bar appearance = NO in plist.
2. The ViewController that you want to make **white** in ViewwillApper add

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
   ```
3. The ViewController that you want to make **Black** in ViewwillApper add

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
   ```